# ShadowMap artifacts when moving on the map

Tags: shadow-mapping

I have a problem which I believe is caused by the fragment shader code I use, however I'm not entirely sure.

The issue is this: I’ve been playing with few examples using Cesium (3D globe) and specifically, with it's shadowMap implementation. In the process, I observed that If I generate a shadowMap, and then zoom or move around on the globe, the shadow detaches or appears and then reappears. If you also observe the green and red areas, they seem to change depending on the zoom and the panning position.

For example, observe the green area in front of the start of the camera: it slowly disappears as I continue to zoom out (also, please find a link to the code demo below the images)

[image]
[image]
[image]

You could also test it by yourself in the sandcastle here:

[Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

Is this a problem with the fragment shader, or it’s something related to the shadowMap itself? Any hints as to where I could fine tune this behavior?

I'm using the latest stable version of Chrome and have a decent GPU.

Comment: What is the depth bias and depth clamp set to?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, they are set to the following:

shadowParameters.depth=distance/radius-0.0003;
shadowParameters.nDotL=clamp(dot(normalEC,-directionEC),0.,1.);